# How to hide dropdown div after clicking aside of its parent menu?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery code and it works fine. Its a simple dropdown menu at the end. Clicking on "topbar" opens up and closes "topbarin" div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.topbar').click(function(){
        $('.topbarin').fadeOut(400);
        if($(this).next('.topbarin').is(":visible"))
        {
        $(this).next('.topbarin').fadeOut(400);
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).next('.topbarin').fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is some HTML also

```
<div class="fr"><div class="topbar">SMS Support phones</div>
            <ul class="topbarin">
              <li>Phone 1</li>
              <li>Phone 2</li></ul>
          </div>
```

But, any chance after clicking aside of that menu for `.topbarin` to simply fade out?

Thx!

Comment: You really should provide a fiddle on this kind of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code after yours, it will fadeout the menu when a click is outsde of the whole menu.

```
$(document).click(function(e){

    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('topbar') ) {
         $('.topbarin').fadeOut(400);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add this code after yours, it will fadeout the menu when a click is outsde of the whole menu.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fr').click(function(){
        $('ul.topbarin').toggle('slide');
    });
});
$(document).click(function(e){

    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('topbar') ) {
         $('.topbarin').fadeOut(400);
    }
});
```

html code

```
<div class="fr">
    <div class="topbar">SMS Support phones</div>
            <ul class="topbarin">
              <li>Phone 1</li>
              <li>Phone 2</li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Code has cool bug (onclick opens up all dropdowns instead the clicked one) in really cool fashion, so +1 I will use it too, sooo thx Ankit!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.topbar, .topbarin li').click(function(){
        $('ul.topbarin').toggle('slide');
    });

})
```

Fiddle link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techblogger/QXf5b/)